# Delete Multiple Records from ListView in ASP.NET using CheckBox in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Using confirmation before delete from ListView using C#. I have a ListView with CheckBox in it and I want to Delete the Items/Records from ListView which are selected with CheckBox in to it.

i.e Multiple select items and then Delete these Multiple Records from ListView

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

would have left this as a comment but for some reason, I can't find where to add a comment...

The ListView control has a CheckedItems collection which you can iterate through, something like:

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems
        lvi.Remove()           
Next
```

Comment: Sorry! But i Need in C#.And i have Binded the ListView using SQLDatasource with CheckBox in to it...!

Answer (score 0):

foreach(ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems lvi)
{
lvi.Remove() 
}