# ListView Multiple Delete (CheckBox)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, listview

sorry in advance I have searched the whole site but I can not find an answer to this question

I plan to use the listview with checkboxes in every item and one delete button so that I can do a removal to multiple row at once, is there any way that I can start this work?

this is my current code

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListInbox" runat="server" DataKeyNames="MessageID" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceInbox" >
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
    There is no message
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
    <table runat="server">
    <tr runat="server">
    <td runat="server">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSelect" runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelMsg" runat="server" Width="400px">
        <a href='UserProfile.aspx?UserName=<%# Eval("FromUserName") %>'><img src="ProfilePic/<%#Eval("User.ProfilePic") %>" alt='' width="25"  /></a>
        <a href='UserProfile.aspx?UserName=<%# Eval("FromUserName") %>'><%# Eval("FromUserName") %></a>
        write you message: 
        <a href='ViewMessages.aspx?MsgID=<%# Eval("MessageID") %>'><%# Eval("Subject") %></a>
        <%# Eval("MessageTime") %>
    </asp:Panel>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr style="text-align:left; width:400px;" />
    </ItemTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>
    <div style="min-height:450px;">
    <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
    </div>
    </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The questions are

1. Where the CheckBox put? Selected/Item template?
2. Where the Delete Button put? Inside/Outside ListView?

Thx in advance..

Comment: omg, in 1 minute someone vote down -1 to my question..im really sorry if this not suitable for you guys

Comment: i've tried both of this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346199/delete-multiple-records-from-listview-in-asp-net-using-checkbox-in-listview
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346199/delete-multiple-records-from-listview-in-asp-net-using-checkbox-in-listview
both not working
i just dont know where to start.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do smth similar with a `GridView` backed with a `DataTable`, I suppose I can give you a general idea and you can do smth similar.

1. Create a flag column/ field. e.g: `User.SetToDelete`
2. `onCheckChanged` set this flag to true.
3. Upon `Click` of the delete button, iterate the rows and look for items set to be deleted.

As for the suggestion for a simple GUI:

[image: Grid with multiple delete]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I should probably start switch to gridview .. thank you very much Mr. Zortkun